# I need to select rows by symbols that contains in the column value. E.g. select ā by a, ē by e etc

Tags: oracle10g

i know that in Oracle you can select rows by symbols that contains in a column value, like :

```
     select * from table where id in (select id from table where name like '%asd%')
```

But i need to select values from database that contains characters like ā,ē,č,ž etc, by a,e,c,z. is it possible in Oracle, and if it is than how ?

i also know :

```
regexp_like(column,'asd|asc|ase|eqw')
```

but there can be word like šķūņu , and when user write for search skunku, than i need to write in regexp all kind of combinations of symbols ā,ķ,ū,ņ... it`s a bad option for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem this way :

```
         Replace(Convert(decompose(signal_custom_fields.field_value),'US7ASCII'),'?')    like '%Riga%'
```

i decompose all characters with ā, than i convert decomposed symbole to ?, and remoove it from the word, and than i compair entered word with all data in data base. is there another way to do it ?